# What's wrong with this "proof" that $\mathbb{R}$ is enumerable?

Tags: computability, enumeration, real-numbers, uncountability

The fake proof:

- We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, hence we cannot enumerate over it.
- But what we do know is that $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rationals, is countable, and even denumerable.
- We also know that we can construct $\mathbb{R}$ through what are called Dedekind cuts.
- We choose to let the partition itself denote a new number and go forth to define mathematical operations on it as to be compatible with the rest of the numbers (mainly $\mathbb{Q}$ and our new number $x$)

*Sidenote: I think so far this is standard, and contains nothing false. The actual argument starts below this line.*

- Let us denote the set containing $x$ as $S_1 := \mathbb{Q}\cup\{x\}$. For convenience, the superscript of $S_1$ is how many new such numbers we have added through the cuts.
- Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, we can enumerate over every single rational $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ to produce an $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Do this process $n$ times and you end up with $S_n = \mathbb{Q}\cup{x_1}\cup{x_2}\cup\dots\cup{x_n}$.
- But $S_n$ is also enumerable since it has a finite more elements than $\mathbb{Q}$.
- **Hence - After enumerating over the entirety of $\mathbb{Q}$ - Start enumerating over the entirety of $S_{|\mathbb{N}|}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$**
- Now we will end up with even newer numbers to put in our set, which we will now call $S_{n = |\mathbb{N}|,k}$ where $n$ represents the enumeration over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $k$ represents the enumeration over $S_{|\mathbb{N}|}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Do this ad infinitum and you will eventually describe $\mathbb{R}$.

I know I went wrong somewhere, I just don't know where.

Comment: "After enumerating over the entirety of $\mathbb{Q}$" if you continue listing elements that is no longer an enumeration. There is no problem anywhere else. You are producing maps from [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) to the real numbers. In the sentence that you highlighted you are allowing yourself to use ordinals larger than the ordinal of the natural numbers. Sure, you can (assuming the well-order principle) get a bijection between some ordinal and the real numbers.

Comment: @plop Correct me if I'm wrong - but one can always accommodate inside a bijection between countable sets a finite amount of new elements, so I'm not sure if I understand how it's no longer an enumeration...

Comment: When you have enumerated the entirety of $\mathbb{Q}$ you have a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. You can append the new elements appending new elements to $\mathbb{N}$. Like $\infty\mapsto x_1$, $\infty+1\mapsto x_2$. The actual names that are used are $\omega_0\mapsto x_1$, $\omega_0+1\mapsto x_2$.

Comment: Just go read about ordinal numbers. Yes, you have (as a given, not by any algorithm) a bijection between the real numbers and an ordinal number (assuming the aiom of choice. Oops, above I said well ordering principle). No, that ordinal number is not going to be bijective to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @plop Thank you, I will

Comment: @plop A nit-pick, in my question, right before the highlight: "But $S_n$ is also enumerable since it has a finite more elements than $\mathbb{Q}$." <- This would be wrong then, as well, correct?

Comment: Not wrong, because you can map $0\mapsto x_1, 1\mapsto x_2,...,n\mapsto x_n$ and $k+r\mapsto $ the rational that you would have mapped $r$ to.

Comment: I have since deleted the last two comments I made due to bloat. (They had absolutely no info, so don't worry)
Most importantly, **ordinal arithmetic is not commutative** so @plop, your construction isn't actually the same as mine. Apparently from asking on math's chat, the placement of the unions do matter. I.e. $3 + \omega_0 = \omega_0$ but $\omega_0 \neq \omega_0 + 3$

Comment: Enumerable is existence of a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. What I am saying is that the claim that $S_n$ is enumerable is not wrong, since it can be mapped to $\mathbb{N}$ as I said. As my first comment was saying, it is the highlighted step what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Do this ad infinitum and you will eventually describe $\mathbb{R}$."

The "ad infinitum" takes uncountably many steps to complete.

Comment: Yes - uncountably in the sense it exceeds $\omega_0$, but not in the sense you run out of ordinals - right? I don't think you *can* run out of ordinals... ever. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: The procedure (if you're careful enough on how you adjoin new numbers, you did not actually make that part of your attempt precise) can suceed after $\omega_1$ steps, where $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal.

Comment: The procedure may never succeed if, if your example, you never add $\sqrt{42}$ to your sets. You need some guarantee that every real will eventually be added.