# Why do we consider enumeration up to $\omega$ instead of leaving it to as many ordinal numbers?

Tags: enumeration

A few minutes ago I asked a question about a "proof" that $\mathbb{R}$ is enumerable that crossed my mind: [What's wrong with this "proof" that $\mathbb{R}$ is enumerable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128356/whats-wrong-with-this-proof-that-mathbbr-is-enumerable)

I was told to look into ordinal numbers, and that after crossing $\omega$ we stop considering something to be an enumeration.

Why is this the case? Are there negative consequences if we don't put this limitation?

Edit:
I always thought of $\mathbb{N}$ as the "counting numbers" - but... when we cross over to ordinals like $\omega$, $\omega+1$, etc, aren't we still effectively counting?

Comment: It is just a definition. Nothing negative or positive. Just a name to put things into categories.

Comment: @plop Thank you - so what would we call an algorithm that goes through a well-ordered set that has an ordinal beyond $w$?

Comment: See [hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation).

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, every set can be well-ordered, so the concept of enumerability becomes empty.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Because we can pick and choose (hence the axiom) an ordering however we like? So is the concept of enumeration really only useful **without** the AoC?

Comment: It is a classical theorem in set theory that the axiom of choice is equivalent to the well-ordering principle.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'll take a look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $S$ is enumerable (or, countable) if we can enumerate it:
$$
S = \{s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots\}
$$
In other words, there is a mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$.

Cantor showed that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't enumerable.

We can consider more relaxed notions of enumeration. For example, a set $S$ is well-orderable if there is a linear order $<$ on $S$ such that any non-empty subset of $S$ has a minimum. This encompasses your examples, and much more.

The axiom of choice is equivalent to the well-ordering principle, which states that every set can be well-ordered. Hence if you assume the axiom of choice, *every* set can be enumerated in this sense.

Comment: I take it in this definition, the enumeration cannot cross $\omega$?

Comment: When you count $1,2,3,\ldots$, do you ever reach $\omega$?

Comment: Haha! Quite... I see your point.

Comment: @Novicegrammer But when you well-order $\mathbb{R}$ you do cross $\omega_0$ and $\omega_0+1$ and $2\omega_0$, and $\omega_0^{\omega_0}$, ... Assuming the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) you won't need to cross $\omega_1$, but if not, then you may have to cross even more ordinals.

Comment: @plop Oh thanks, I've been introduced to yet another hypothesis. ...I'll throw this somewhere in the backlog of stuff I have to read.